# Code error with regard to the syntax adds padding to the right of the string

Tags: python, csv, formatting

Can someone help me solve this valueError:

```
def movie_fetch_data(movie_csv):
    with open(movie_csv, "r") as movie_file:
        reader = csv.reader(movie_file)
        movie_info = []
        for row in reader:
            movie_info.append(row)
        return movie_info    

''' The data has been printed as a linked list'''

def movie_print_data(data):
    for title, genre, rotten, grass, year in data:
        print("{:36} {:10} {:18} ${:16} {}".format(title, genre, rotten, grass, year))

movie_data = movie_fetch_data(movie_csv) 
movie_print_data(movie_data)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [23], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 movie_data = movie_fetch_data(movie_csv) 
----> 2 movie_print_data(movie_data)`your text`

Input In [22], in movie_print_data(data)
      1 def movie_print_data(data):
----> 2     for title, genre, rotten, grass, year in data:
      3         print("{:36} {:10} {:18} ${:16} {}".format(title, genre, rotten, grass, year))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)
```

I tried to create the function `movie_print_data` that takes the parameter data. I wanted to use the unpacking method to be able to reference each element of the list.

Comment: At least one row of the CSV doesn't provide as much items as you expect or the CSV reader needs configuration to read the file correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, the issue you have is caused by your underlying CSV missing data. Tuple unpacking is not a suitable approach when you can't guarantee the number of elements in a sequence as:

1. You can't determine which element is missing
2. And thus error handling becomes very challenging.

**A quick fix could be fill the missing data with empty strings when you read in the data**. This way any steps you do after reading in the data can be sure that any downstream steps can rely on the data:

````
```
EXPECTED_VALUES_PER_ROW = 5

def row_has_all_values(row: list) -> bool:
    return EXPECTED_VALUES_PER_ROW == len(row)

def get_num_missing_values(row: list) -> int:
    return EXPECTED_VALUES_PER_ROW - len(row)

def pad_row_with_empty_stings(row: list, missing_values: int) -> list:
    null_padding = [""] * missing_values
    return [*row, *null_padding] 

def movie_fetch_data(movie_csv):

    with open(movie_csv, "r") as movie_file:
        reader = csv.reader(movie_file)
        movie_info = []

        for row in reader:
            
            if not row_has_all_values(row):
                num_missing_values = get_num_missing_values(row)
                row = pad_row_with_empty_stings(row, num_missing_values)
            movie_info.append(row)

        return movie_info   
```
````